# Problem continuing the enumeration automatically

Tags: enumitem

I use the package `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`  and in the main document I use the command

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{*}}, series=myenumeration]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{*}}, series=myenumerationb ,  resume=myenumeration]
```

These two lines of code work flawlessly and the enumeration continues as expected. If I add however,

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{*}}, series=myenumerationc ,  resume=myenumerationb]
```

The enumeration resets back to 1. Why? How can I fix it?

**Addendum**

Full MWE to see the problem.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic{*}}, series=enumerationa]
        \item Hello
        
        \item World
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic{*}}, series=enumerationb, resume=enumerationa]
        \item Bye Bye
        
        \item World
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic{*}}, series=enumerationc, resume=enumerationb]
        \item I'm in trouble
        
        \item World
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps because series `myenumerationc` has not been stated before. I don't think `resume` takes a parameter.  Please keep in mind that is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yeah, sorry added an MWE,.

Answer (score 1):

The `series` construction allows you to have several independent, non-overlapping streams. E.g.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic{*}}, series=enumerationa]
        \item Hello
        
        \item World
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic{*}}, series=enumerationb]
        \item Bye Bye
        
        \item World
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic{*}}, resume=enumerationa]
        \item I'm 3
        
        \item I'm 4
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic{*}}, resume=enumerationb]
        \item I'm 3 again
        
        \item I'm 4
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic{*}}, resume=enumerationa]
        \item I'm 5
        
        \item I'm 6
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**You should never be specifying both `series=...` and `resume=...` for the options to the same list**. What you did by specifying `series=enumb resume=enuma` does **not** set "`enumb`" to be somehow equal to "`enuma`". Instead the `series=enumb` is basically inoperative, as `resume=enuma` kicks in. So when you try to "resum" `enumb` later, it is picking up a series that was never used at all.